# Azure sql Database suggestion

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We have DB in on-premise of size around 3TB. We have to move this to azure cloud. What would be the best and cost effective solution? We have an idea to split the DB into multiple DB so that we can reduce the cost of azure sql DB storage? Please suggest us best option here(azure sql DB, sql instance or VM).

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL Database and Azure SQL Managed Instance are the best options to migrate the existing on premises SQL database to Azure because:

- No need to setup infrastructure
- Scalable
- High Availability (99.99%)
- Easy to migrate using Data Migration Service

You can choose any of the below mentioned Service tier in Azure SQL database to migrate the database:

- General purpose (up to maximum 4 TB database size)
- Hyperscale (support for up to 100 TB of database size)

Meanwhile, **Azure SQL Managed Instance has two service tiers: General purpose and Business Critical**. In General purpose tier, maximum of 16TB storage is supported with more than 8vCore. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/resource-limits#service-tier-characteristicsa) for more more details and comparison between service tiers.

Please visit [Azure SQL Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/sql-managed-instance-paas-overview) to know more.

Lastly, check the [Features comparison: Azure SQL Database and Azure SQL Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/features-comparison#features-of-sql-database-and-sql-managed-instance) and choose the best.

Comment: Thanks for your information. We planned to go for Azure sql databse. Is there anyway to reduce the cost by splitting DB into multiple small DB(so we don’t need to pay for high vCore and storage)? Is there anyway to reduce the cost by architectural ways?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no point of dividing db into small db because any ways it is going to cost same. you can [request a pricing cost](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/contact-sales/) and talk to sales specialist directly for better insight.